# NSIS Language selection dialog on top

Tags: nsis

I'm using MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY in an installer, and I need the language selection dialog appears on top, so it can't be hidden by other windows. I'm already making the installer on top, using:

```
System::Call "user32::SetWindowPos(i $HWNDPARENT, i ${HWND_TOPMOST}, i0, i0, i0, i0, i ${SWP_NOSIZE}|${SWP_NOMOVE})"
```

I looked [LangDLL.c](http://nsis.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.28/LangDLL_8c-source.html) and dialog seems to be created with:

```
DialogBox(g_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG), 0, DialogProc);
```

But I don't know how to continue.

Could I use that system call with a different HWND to make the language selection dialog be on top?

Comment: Why do you feel this is necessary? Forcing windows to be always on top is annoying IMHO.

Comment: It's not me, it's my customer who wants it. The installer is already forced to be on top, so he wants the language selection to also be on top.

Answer (score 0):

`DialogBox` creates a modal dialog so there is no easy way to interact with it using the System plug-in.

You could try editing LangDll.dll with [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) and add the `WS_EX_TOPMOST` extended style. If that does not work then you would have to recompile LangDll and add a call to `SetWindowPos` in `WM_INITDIALOG`...

Comment: I tried adding WS_EX_TOPMOST, but it gets removed whenever I try to compile the script.  I'll try to recompile LangDll...